# Ansible SSH Error

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am running into a weird ssh related error in ansible 1.9.4 on ubuntu 14.04.

In my inventory file I have several servers defined in groups something like:

```
[group1]
g1-server1
g1-server2

[group2]
g2-server1
g2-server2
....
[dev]
g1-server1 .... 
g2-server1 ...
etc.....
```

All servers are now pointing to localhost for testing. There are also several variables I am assigning to each server.

I can run playbook task by task (using tags) and sometimes the same task works, sometimes it doesn't. If I run the entire playbook it will stop at random location with this error:

```
fatal: [hostname] => SSH Error: Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints    
SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

I suspect it may be an issue with many ssh connections at the same time from localhost to localhost, but I am not sure how to confirm this. Also, I have much greater success with tasks if they are marked run_once: true.

Does anyone have any ideas on this on?

Note: I tried to find some resources on interwebs on this; there are several discussions related to server rebooting. However keep in mind I am not rebooting anything here.

Comment: Could you post your `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: To clarify further, each host has ansible_ssh_host specified, currently pointing to localhost.

Comment: did you try what is proposed in the error?

Comment: Yea, I don't get any more information on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you are opening multiple connections which do the same thing (for example changing the same files). This of course will cause unpredictable results.

Despite the fact that I do not see any sense in this sort of testing, you can eliminate the error setting

```
serial: 1
```

in your playbook, see: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size

which will cause the tasks to run one after another

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and serial: 1 was not  an option for me. I updated the  ansible.cfg and set the properties under 
`[ssh_connection]`
`ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPersist=60s`

Mainly set ControlMaster to no. This made my playbooks more stable.