# node-ansible fails to connect to the host when multiple connections coexist

Tags: node.js, ansible

I have an API server which may trigger multiple [node-ansible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ansible)s simultaneously to connect to a remote machine to do something.

Here's the node.js code:

```
// app.js
const Ansible = require('node-ansible')

let ansibleNum = 10

for (let i = 0; i < ansibleNum; i += 1) {
let command = new Ansible.Playbook().playbook('test')
command.inventory('hosts')
command.exec()
    .then(successResult => {
    console.log(successResult)
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    })
}
```

And the ansible playbook:

```
# test.yml
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Test Ansible
      shell: echo hello
      register: result  # store the result into a variable called "result"
    - debug: var=result.stdout_lines
```

As `ansibleNum` increases, the probability of the failure of ansible playbook also increases.

The failure message is:

`fatal: [10.50.123.123]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 10.50.123.123 closed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}`

I've read another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722099/ansible-ssh-error), but the solutions provided by it doesn't work in my case.

Another way to trigger the problem is by executing

`ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml & ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml`.

This command runs ansible without node.js.

I've pushed the code to [github](https://github.com/lyenliang/TestAnsible). You can download it directly.

Anyone knows why the shared connection got closed?

I've set `ControlMaster` argument to `auto` by following the document [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#openssh-specific-settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that setting the connection type to `paramiko` solves my problem.

Here's the config file located in  `~/.ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
transport = paramiko
```

Based on this [document](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#transport), it seems that paramiko doesn't support persistent connection.

I'm still confused about why this setting solves my problem.